# Upload LOB mobile app to Azure Intune programmatically

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I'm trying to add mobile application to my Azure tenant Intune programmatically. I can upload metadata for my app to the Intune but I can't upload my app binaries and as a result I can't install this application to the enrolled device. 
I understand that after creating application metadata I have to upload application binaries and commit them with /commit endpoint but I can't find any info how to do this.